# How to install and compile C++ code on CentOS and RedHat Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, centos, redhat

I am currently using CentOS. I have tried installing g++ but there terminal shows `Error: Unable to find a match`.

Comment: Hey, I think you need to install C++ on fresh CentOS. Use `yum install gcc-g++` or something. Please google it though. Also, please go through [Asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for understanding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Using `yum install gcc-c++` you can install c++ compiler.
2. Now, you can run `g++ HelloWorld.cpp` to compile.
3. To run the program type `./a.out` in terminal.

Comment: Even easier test to see if all is installed, `g++ --version`, no code required.